# Why collapsing toolbar title is under toolbar?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

My activity design like below:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/movie_detail_appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/movie_detail_collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/movie_detail_header_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="#99000026"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="10">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/detail_movie_poster"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="110dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/no_movie_image" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="9"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/detail_movie_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="26sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/detail_movie_original_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/detail_movie_genres"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/movie_detail_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/movie_detail_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/movie_detail_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

But design happened like that. Collapsing toolbar title is under the toolbar.

[image]

Also I used this `initCollapsingToolbar()` for dynamically collapsing toolbar title :

```
private void initCollapsingToolbar() {
    final CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
collapsingToolbar.setTitle(" ");
AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appbar);
appBarLayout.setExpanded(true);

// hiding & showing the title when toolbar expanded & collapsed
appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
    boolean isShow = false;
    int scrollRange = -1;

    @Override
    public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
        if (scrollRange == -1) {
            scrollRange = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
        }
        if (scrollRange + verticalOffset == 0) {
            Results results = intent.getParcelableExtra(Constant.PARCELABLE_MOVIE_TITLE);
                collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(results.getTitle());
            isShow = true;
        } else if (isShow) {
            collapsingToolbar.setTitle(" ");
            isShow = false;
        }
       }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved this problem. My solution is here

Firstly i added `app:titleEnabled="false"` to `CollapsingToolbar`

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/movie_detail_collapsing_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
    app:titleEnabled="false">
```

and then change `collapsingToolbar.setTitle();` to `getSupportActionBar().setTitle();`
 in `initCollapsingToolbar()`

and finally added `app:titleMarginTop="14dp"` to `toolbar`

Maybe this solution is bad way but that's all I can do.

Answer (score 1):

change `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` under collapseToolbarLayout

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=231738&q=stars%3D1%20attachments%3D3%20type%3Adefect&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened) only in emulator, real device is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. The toolbar title was cutting off from bottom.
Adding some arbitrary bottom margin i in `<toolbar>`.

Added `app:titleMarginBottom="44dp"` to `<toolbar>`

[image]